# Check only if a value is present in a vector

Tags: r

In a dataframe column, can we check only if a value is present. Example, `asd$a` has 3 values.
So if I want see if it contains only "A", it should return true. In below case , it should return FALSE, since it contains "A","B" and "C". Similarly, We need to check if it contains only "A" and "C" and so on

```
asd <- data.frame(a = c("A","B","C"), b = c(1,2,3))
```

Answer (score 2):

Just put an all around it `all(df$a=="A")`.
Second option `all(df$a=="A" | df$a=="B")`.

Comment: perfect and thanks